# Consultar un numero de una tabla

Tags: sql

tengo una inquietud muy grande y no he podido encontrar una solución todavía, mi inquietud es saber si hay como buscar un número máximo antes de llegar a otro número el cual es mayor pero le dí esa numeración para limitar el acceso.

Es decir, tengo mi tabla sql con unos códigos donde puse unos items y a parte puse un item con la numeración del ultimo ítem que se puede generar (ancho de columna: 2 dígitos), digamos que del 1 al 12 puse unos items y tengo el ítem 99 hay forma de obviar el ítem 99 para que solo me de que el ultimo numero ocupado es el 12 y que me retorne ese número? (no quiero borrar el 99 de la tabla)

Comment: Algo como `select max(id) from tabla where id<>99`?

Comment: Probablemente mejor ```SELECT max(id) FROM tabla WHERE id < 99```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claro que se puede, lo que debes hacer es excluir el registro con un filtro `where`, para obtener el máximo, sería algo como:

```
select max(numero) NumeroMaximoMenora99
  from Item
 where numero < 99;
```

Comment: Te faltó el `as` después de `max(numero)`, no pude editar tu respuesta porque es una edición menor a 6 caracteres.

Comment: Marc, el `as` regularmente es opcional, depende quizás del motor. Yo regularmente no lo utilizo, pues siento que las consultas son más difíciles de leer con tanto `as` por allì.

Comment: Gracias no lo sabia, lo probaré (yo casi siempre he usado MS SQL, My SQL y algo de Oracle)

Comment: En ninguno de esos tres es necesario el `as`, te invito a comprobarlo. Un saludo.

Comment: El 'as' es para nombrar de alguna forma el resultado: en SQL Server saldría la columna sin nombre. Sólo tomar en cuenta que la respuesta de jachguate sólo traerá el resultado que sea menor a 99. Si algún día llegaras a tener, por ejemplo, consecutivos hasta el 100, esta sentencia te traería el 98, y siempre el 98. Por eso en mi comentario te había puesto la comparación con '<>', así no importa cuánto crezca tu tabla, siempre excluirá el 99. ¡Saludos!